# 複数ファイルの一括ダウンロード

Tags: javascript, html, html5, asp.net, internet-explorer

Webブラウザで
1. Webページ上の「ダウンロード」リンクをクリックしたら、フォルダ選択のダイアログを表示
2. ユーザーが選択したフォルダに複数のファイルを一括でダウンロード
3. ダウンロードするファイル数は不定（サーバー側で決定）

このような要件があるのですが、何らかの方法で実現できるものなのでしょうか。
たとえば、ブラウザの特定のアドオンやプラグインを使用すれば実現できるとか。

クライアントＯＳは Windows（７以降）です。
ブラウザは Internet Explorer（11以降）が望ましいですが、他のブラウザでも構いません。
サーバーサイドは ASP.NET が前提ですが、他のプラットフォームで実現できるのであれば、それでも良いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

デフォルトの権限では出来ません。
また各ブラウザで手法が異なります。

[JavaScriptからローカルファイルを作成する方法まとめ - あらびき日記](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/a_bicky/20110718/1311027391)

ここが参考になるかと思います。

尚、この場合フォルダ選択が出来ませんので保存パスを入力(選択ではなく)させるUIを自作する必要があります。

Comment: なるほど。IEでは`FileSystemObject`が使えるんですね。ただし、インターネットオプションのセキュリティ設定を変更する必要があると。セキュリティ設定の変更なしでは無理ですよね・・・

Answer (score 1):

すべての要件を満たすためには各ブラウザ用のアドオンを作成することになるでしょう。

簡単かつ確実な方法として、ZIPファイルをサーバサイドで作成しそれをダウンロードさせる方法はいいかがでしょうか。

まら、とにかく複数ファイルをダウンロードさせるだけであれば、

```js
window.open('a.bin');
window.open('b.bin');
window.open('c.bin');
```

で可能です。が、利用者側の立場ではおすすめしたくないです。